Extracting entities and "fuzzy" relationships from Wikipedia articles to reason across a graph
I have a goal of being able to take some prose, like a Wikipedia article:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_democracy
and build a knowledge graph from it to reason across. Most of the examples I've seen have very strict ontologies, e.g., this excellent article:
https://medium.com/mantisnlp/constructing-a-knowledge-base-with-spacy-and-spacy-llm-f65b50ea534d
I know about wikidata, which also seems to deal in very well-defined relationships between entities, but I'm looking to capture "fuzzier" connections. If you look at the above wiki article you see sentences like this:
"Other socialists criticize social democracy because it serves to devise new means to strengthen the capitalist system, which conflicts with the socialist goal of replacing capitalism with a socialist system.[223]"
I'm wanting to capture relationships like:

(Other socialists), criticize, (social democracy), because, (social democracy), serves to devise new means to strengthen, (the capitalist system)
(social democracy), conflicts with, (the socialist goal), of replacing, (capitalism), with, (a socialist system)

I want to be able to capture the relationships between relationships, if that makes sense. For example:

(Other socialists), criticize, (social democracy) = A
(A happens), because, ((social democracy), serves to devise new means to strengthen, (the capitalist system) = B)
B, conflicts with, ((the socialist goal), of replacing, (capitalism), with, (a socialist system) = c)

Hopefully that makes sense in that we haven't broken relationships down into atomic and unambiguous terms, but the entities are valid and the relationships between them, e.g.,
"serves to devise new means to strengthen" still carries useful information.
I ultimately want to be able to reason across a body of text to find answers to questions like, "In what ways does social democracy both support and confront capitalism?", where the answers are ONLY derived from the source text, are 100% accurate (i.e., no hallucinations and 100% grounded in the connections between entities), and any inferences can be traced back precisely to a set of entities and relationships in the source text.
I feel like the key is ensure that any inference always starts from a known structure of entities and relationships (however vague), as opposed to feeding the whole context to an LLM and hoping it comes up with something sensible without exactly understanding what its inferences are based on. LLMs are amazing at coming up with educated guesses that are mostly right most of the time, but that's just not good enough for most serious applications. You still need some actor in the system that "understands" or is constrained by an underlying structure.
I've been able to process the above wiki article into a sequences of python objects that capture the main elements of a wiki page (sentences, entity links as  tags, sentence references), got noun chunks from spacy, correlating those chunks with  tags for entities. I can build a graph from there but it's the chained reasoning and fuzzy relationships bits I'm struggling with.
Any thoughts? :-)
